# Group By Gridview

Tags: asp.net

I want to show records in gridview in mentioned below format:

```
ID     NAME     ADDRESS
1      A1       A111
2      A11      XX
3      A111     XXX
4      B12      XXXX
5      C12      X
```

Please help to get this issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It's not **Groub By**. Just you use Order By in query. You'll get list same as you want.

Use in Query:
Order By Name, Address

Answer (score 0):

This is a demo of a grid view, may be you can look through it.

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
   <Columns>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Label ID="lblserial" runat="server">
                        </asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" 
                             ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="Name">
                         <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                         </asp:BoundField>
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" 
                             ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="Address">
                         <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                         </asp:BoundField>
       </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource 
        ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:yourConnectionstring %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT Name,Address FROM [Table_Name] WHERE (Condition)"
        >
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="Name" SessionField="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="Address" SessionField="Address" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>


        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code Behind

```
     int i = 1;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        Label lbl = (Label)row.FindControl("lblserial");
        lbl.Text = i.ToString();
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Actually I am looking record in below format:
like 1=>2=>3
     1=>4
     1=>5
Id 1 have their sub records (id 2,3), so under 1st row there is second row i.e. id=2 and id 2 contains another sub record i.e. id=3.